# Is serialize function stable on objects?

Tags: php, serialization

When it comes to serialization of objects which do not implement `__sleep` /  `Serializable` is `serialize` function stable? e.g. does it return the same representation on equal objects without regard of construction process, order in which properties were assigned with values, etc?

When `__sleep` is implemented does `serialize` follow the order of the property array returned from `__sleep`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are asking and not trying it for yourself? Did you run into something unexpected?

Comment: Cause testing can not prove that it is stable only the reverse.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of its instability and point out what you expected versus what actually happened? PHP version *could* be important so include that as well.

Comment: My previous comment was misleading. I do not have examples of instability, I'm only saying I can't prove stability with testing.

Comment: Not sure why the order of property assignments would be relevant. Could you give an example where it would be?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to prove stability; maybe someone who is familiar with the source code would be able to shed light on the inner workings. Do your fear accepting stability in the absence of instability?

Comment: Order of assignments is one assumption about row of factors which could possibly  impact output of serialization. There could also be instantiation with or without `__construct` and many others.

Comment: Yes, I expect someone with the insight in details of implementation of `serialize` could answer of this question. The case where stability matters is hashing of serialization representation of an object.

Comment: Well, you could be waiting a while to get your answer because I doubt that many good C developers are perusing the PHP tag. [If you were able to identify which code handles serialization](https://github.com/php/php-src) then you might be able to ask an on-topic question in the C tag but as for the PHP tag most people are concerned with how to use it rather than the underlying implementation. I think this question is interesting so I wish you luck!

Comment: AFAIK `__construct` is not involved in unserialising an object, nor any other method calls besides `__wakeup`. It can't be, since PHP doesn't know what arguments were passed to `__construct`. It's simply creating an object in memory of a certain class and re-assigns all property values. As such, order of operation shouldn't matter. And you can confirm that experimentally by adding `echo` statements in `__construct`.